# How to display response message from a HttpResponseErrInterceptor to a specific controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have a post request on my createController.js, but my onError promise is not working.

```
ManageCaseOutlineServices.getInsert({
 table: 'manageCaseOutline'}, self.caseOutlineHeader).then(function (response) {
    self.isLoading = false;
    self.successMessage = "Record Successfully Saved";
    self.openAlertModal('success');
    }, function (error) {
    self.isLoading = false;  
    console.log(error.data); //this line code is not displaying.
});
```

As I debugged my code I saw that I have a HttpResponseErrInterceptor configured in my maincontroller.js, so I think that's why onError is not working.

```
module.factory('HttpResponseErrInterceptor',
    function($q, $location, $timeout, $rootScope, apiConfig, ErrorLogger) {
        return {
            responseError : function(response) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            switch (response.status) {
                case 403:
                ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                break;
                case 404:
                ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                break;
                case 422:
                console.log(response.data);                 
                break;
                case 504:
                ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                break;
                case 502:
                ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                break;
                case 500:
                ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                break;
            }
            $rootScope.isLoading = false;

            return defer.promise;
                            }
                        };
                    });

    module.config([ '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('BearerAuthInterceptor');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpResponseErrInterceptor');
    } ]);
```

I added an error code 422 in the switch statement above which is my error code from my response. And I tried to add console log and it is logged when I get an error 422 on my other controller.

Now my question is how can I access that error response to a specific controller so that I will be able to display it in my HTML view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error intercepter needs to re-throw the error:

```
module.factory('HttpResponseErrInterceptor',
    function($q, $location, $timeout, $rootScope, apiConfig, ErrorLogger) {
        return {
            responseError : function(response) {
                ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶
                switch (response.status) {
                    case 403:
                    ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                    break;
                    case 404:
                    ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                    break;
                    case 422:
                    console.log(response.data);                 
                    break;
                    case 504:
                    ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                    break;
                    case 502:
                    ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                    break;
                    case 500:
                    ErrorLogger.logError(response);
                    break;
                }
                $rootScope.isLoading = false;

                ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶.̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶;̶
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module.controller('myctrl',function($scope,ErrorLogger){
ErrorLogger.responseError (response);
}
```

You can directly inject this interceptor inside your controller and pass the response setting the status code to the response as 422 which will inturn enter inside the switch case and populate your logs

Answer (score 0):

You can use $broadcast from [angularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for specific error code, and with help of $on you can catch the event in any controller of the app.

Interceptor

```
module.factory('HttpResponseErrInterceptor',
function($q, $location, $timeout, $rootScope, apiConfig, ErrorLogger) {
    return {
        responseError : function(response) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        switch (response.status) {
            case 403:
            $rootScope.$broadcast('responseError', response);
            break;
           ...
```

any controller of your app

```
 $rootScope.$on('responseError', function (event, response) {
      ErrorLogger.logError(response);
    });
```